# df.to_sql not working [HY04] - Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

I am fairly new to Python, at least to these kinds of problems, and have been struggling with this for days!

I have used df.to_sql for quite a bit of time and for a lot of different dataframes, but have now experienced the following issue/Error:

> DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')

My code looks as follows:

```
**pyodbc.pooling = False
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={SQL Server};Server=[ServerName];Database=DatabaseName")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)**

df.to_sql('Table_Name', 
        con = engine,
            if_exists='replace')
```

I have used the code for a lot of different dataframes, and have no clue what has changed for this particular data? It is from a JSON-file, which I have flattened.

Any ideas, as to what might cause this?

I am not using Linux or anything.

My Dataframe looks as follows:

```
       eventId
0      97592224      3361    1609  2086192          1H     0.491250        8   
1      97592225     49876    1609  2086192          1H     3.649639        8   
2      97592168     14853    1631  2086192          1H     5.356103        8   
3      97592169      8730    1631  2086192          1H     8.653246        8   
4      97592170     14763    1631  2086192          1H    10.219569        8   
...         ...       ...     ...      ...         ...          ...      ...   
1667  586886958     14870    1612  2086209          2H  2915.347568        2   
1668  586886947      8292    1624  2086209          2H  2924.483590        3   
1669  586886948    269676    1624  2086209          2H  2926.881486        1   
1670  586886959     25393    1612  2086209          2H  2927.766165        1   
1671  586886949     13484    1624  2086209          2H  2929.858276        8
```

```
      eventName  subEventId subEventName  positions.0.x  positions.0.y
0          Pass          85  Simple pass             51             51   
1          Pass          83    High pass             35             48   
2          Pass          85  Simple pass             39             12   
3          Pass          83    High pass             34             23   
4          Pass          82    Head pass             65             24   
...         ...         ...          ...            ...            ...   
1667       Foul          24      Protest             37             90   
1668  Free Kick          36     Throw in             64              0   
1669       Duel          10     Air duel             77             23   
1670       Duel          10     Air duel             23             77   
1671       Pass          83    High pass             74             27
```

```
      positions.1.x  positions.1.y  tags.0.id  tags.1.id  tags.2.id tags
0              35.0           48.0     1801.0        NaN        NaN  NaN   
1              61.0           88.0     1802.0        NaN        NaN  NaN   
2              34.0           23.0     1801.0        NaN        NaN  NaN   
3              65.0           24.0     1801.0        NaN        NaN  NaN   
4              85.0           22.0     1801.0        NaN        NaN  NaN   
...             ...            ...        ...        ...        ...  ...   
1667            NaN            NaN     1702.0        NaN        NaN  NaN   
1668           77.0           23.0     1801.0        NaN        NaN  NaN   
1669           74.0           27.0      701.0     1802.0        NaN  NaN   
1670           26.0           73.0      703.0     1801.0        NaN  NaN   
1671            NaN            NaN     1802.0        NaN        NaN  NaN
```

Edited:

The DataFrame can be downloaded using this link: **https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r_zpj-24Unb9XXyYlVNwBkMU_YaKC2ll/view?usp=sharing**

Comment: Please create a minimal DataFrame that will trigger the error, use `df.to_pickle("pickled.gz")` to serialize it into a disk file, then post a download link for that file so that others can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Hi @Gord , a sample of the dataframe can be downloaded using the following [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r_zpj-24Unb9XXyYlVNwBkMU_YaKC2ll/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check the value in the `tags` column of the row with index 8. It appears to be an empty series, and that seems to be messing up the works. I can avoid the `to_sql` error if I do `df.iloc[8, 17] = None` first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Much appreciated!!